# Homeomorphisms between a circle and a square

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

If $A$ is $S^1$, $B$ is a unit square (only the boundary) and $f:A\rightarrow B$ is any homeomorphism then does $x$ and $y$ being antipodal points on the circle imply their images $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ will be ‘antipodal’ on the square in the sense that the length of the path connecting $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ is equal to $2$ ?

Comment: What will happen to the corners?

Comment: The answer is clearly "no". Please don't just ask. [Work a little and include your attempts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) to solve your provle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can easily construct homeomorphisms of $S^1$ to $S^1$ that do not preserve antipodal points, and then compose one of those with a map that radially projects points on $S^1$ to the square to get a map which also doesn't preserve antipodal points.

For the former, for example, map the upper half of the circle to only the first quarter, and then map the lower half ("$3\times$ faster") to the other three quarters.